# Initialize Variables from File

Tags: python, csv, variables

I'm initializing a long list of variables:

```
Var1 = "Apple"
Var2 = "Banana"
...
Var100 = "Pear
```

I'm wondering if I can keep this list in a csv - VarX in col A; "=" in col B (?); and/or FRUIT in col C (or B if don't need "=").  I don't think I can use csv.DictReader.  Is there a way to initialize the long list of variables by importing the file?

Comment: So your file would look like `Var1,=,Apple`…? How's that any better than what you currently have?

Comment: You could use a ``dict`` to store your named variables and the use ``json.dump`` to write it to a file and ``json.load`` to load it from a file.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `.csv` is the wrong kind of file for what you are trying to do. Take a look at the module `configparser`. That will read a file like this:

```
[Values]
Var1 = Apple
Var2 = Banana
...
Var100 = Pear
```

Then your program can do

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()  # Python 2
config = configparser.ConfigParser()  # Python 3
config.read("example.ini")
Var1=config.get("Values", "Var1")
```

In Python 3 you can treat `config["Values"]` pretty much as if it were a `dict`, which will be useful if you don't want to initialize the variables one by one.

Comment: It needs pointing out that the difference in syntax is so minimal (compared to `Var1 = 'Apple'` that it hardly makes sense to do this vs. just writing a Python file…

Comment: It isn't about the syntax but about the intent. There is a difference between reading configuration data and importing executable code. A minor syntax error in the imported file will cause the entire program to fail at `import` time. A program that reads a config file can be deal with that much more robustly.

Comment: I'll grant that point, but I wouldn't think that's the reason OP is choosing this route.